# Javascript Function Works on Local Server but not Online

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, local

So I have this `javascript` game that works on my local server but once I put it online, one of the functions stops working. It may have something to do with permissions of the cookies I am storing for the high score. Can someone please point out what may be wrong.

```
    //Save Highscore if score is greater
 function saveScore() {
     loadScore();
     if (score > highscore) {
         var date = new Date();
         date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 5);
         var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
         document.cookie = "score=" + score + expires + "; path=/";
     }
 }

 //Load High Score
 function loadScore() {
     var cookiearray = document.cookie.split(';');
     for (var i = 0; i < cookiearray.length; i++) {
         var name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[0];
         var value = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];
         if (name == "score") {
             //alert("Score Found!");
             highscore = value;
         }
     }
     return highscore;
 }

 //Lost game function
 function Lost() {
     saveScore();
     loadScore();
     var lost = document.getElementById("lost");
     var hs = document.getElementById("hs");
     lost.style.visibility = "visible";
     postscore.innerHTML = score;
     hs.innerHTML = highscore;
     lost.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
         window.location.reload();
     });
 }
```

Comment: Which function doesn't work?

Comment: Now, define "stops working." You don't give enough information for people to be able to help.

Comment: It doesn't run when it is called

Comment: maybe cached on server/browser?

Comment: hit f12 and see what error is being thrown, tell us what it says in the javascript console.

Comment: "ReferenceError: highscore is not defined"

Comment: did you define it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, I'm guessing that you've modified your code over time but have always had a saved cookie since it became necessary to have one.  In your code sample, if the cookie doesn't exist, `highscore` is never going to be assigned before it's used.  You should have some function that runs on page load that looks for the cookie and if it doesn't exist, initializes the beginning state to known values.

Moreover, I would suggest that an object-oriented approach might be more robust.  In particularly, I'd create a dedicated object for cookie-handling - which properly handles the case where the cookie doesn't exist - and a separate object or objects for the game.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) - an example of a cookie handler

```
var docCookies = {
  getItem: function (sKey) {
    return decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1")) || null;
  },
  setItem: function (sKey, sValue, vEnd, sPath, sDomain, bSecure) {
    if (!sKey || /^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/i.test(sKey)) { return false; }
    var sExpires = "";
    if (vEnd) {
      switch (vEnd.constructor) {
        case Number:
          sExpires = vEnd === Infinity ? "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT" : "; max-age=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case String:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case Date:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd.toUTCString();
          break;
      }
    }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(sValue) + sExpires + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "") + (bSecure ? "; secure" : "");
    return true;
  },
  removeItem: function (sKey, sPath, sDomain) {
    if (!sKey || !this.hasItem(sKey)) { return false; }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" + ( sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + ( sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "");
    return true;
  },
  hasItem: function (sKey) {
    return (new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=")).test(document.cookie);
  },
  keys: /* optional method: you can safely remove it! */ function () {
    var aKeys = document.cookie.replace(/((?:^|\s*;)[^\=]+)(?=;|$)|^\s*|\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?(?:\1|$)/g, "").split(/\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?;\s*/);
    for (var nIdx = 0; nIdx < aKeys.length; nIdx++) { aKeys[nIdx] = decodeURIComponent(aKeys[nIdx]); }
    return aKeys;
  }
};
```

One potential implementation of the elements of your game as an object, loaded in an immediately invoked function that uses the cookie handler above.

```
(function(cookieHandler) {
    // Game constructor
    var Game = function(cookieHandler) {
        this.init(cookieHandler);
    };

    // initializes the game variables, sets up and binds the event handlers
    Game.prototype.init = function(cookieHandler) {
       this.scoreCookie = 'score';
       this.score = 0;
       this.highScore = this.loadScore();
       this.cookieHandler = cookieHandler;
       this.lostElem = document.getElementById("lost");
       this.postScoreElem = null; // don't see this defined anywhere
       this.highScoreElem = document.getElementById("hs");

       this.setUpHandlers()
           .bind();
    };

    // create handlers for the events
    Game.prototype.setupHandlers = function() {
        this.lostHandler = this.lost.bind(this);
        return this;
    };

    // bind the handlers to events
    Game.prototype.bind = function() {
        // there should probably be a binding for some event
        // to invoke the lost handler (lostHandler)
        this.lostElem.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            window.location.reload();
        });
    };

    // save the current score, if higher than the current high score, to
    // the game cookie
    Game.prototype.saveScore = function() {
        if (this.score > this.highScore) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 5);
            this.cookieHandler.setItem(this.scoreCookie, score, date, '/');
        }
    };

    // retrieves the high game score from the cookie, initializes it to zero
    // if there is no cookie.
    Game.prototype.loadScore = function () {
        this.highScore = 0;
        if (this.cookieHandler.hasItem(this.scoreCookie)) {
            this.highScore = parseInt(this.cookieHandler.getItem(this.scoreCookie,10);
        }
    };

    // when the game is lost, update the high and save the current score
    // if it is a new high score.  Signal that the game was lost.            
    Game.prototype.lost = function() {
        this.loadScore();
        this.saveScore();
        this.lostElem.style.visibility = "visible"
        // this.postScoreElem.innerHTML = score;
        this.highScoreElem.innerHTML = highscore;
    };

    var game = new Game(docCookies);
)(docCookies);
```

Comment: I'm more of a java programmer and their OOP approaches are different

Comment: @user3010773 - it uses a different type of object approach, but your designs can be very similar once you've adapted to object prototyping.

Comment: In fact, I'd say that my example actually is pretty poor.  It really should be separated into an MVC pattern with the bulk of what I've shown just being the persistence service.  Basically I was just trying to demonstrate how you could "objectivize" what you had and improve it.